# How to save image file in src/main/resources/images in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the upload file option in jsp and the images are being uploaded in `src\main\webapp\upload` directory.Instead I want,the image to be upload in `src\main\resources\images` folder.I want to check at first whether if there is images folder or not and if there is no any images folder,then i want to make a new folder images.

Here is what I tried:

```
@Service
public class EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository empRepository;

    public Employee saveEmployee(HttpServletRequest request, Employee employee){
        // Root Directory.
        String uploadRootPath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("upload");
        System.out.println("uploadRootPath=" + uploadRootPath);

        File uploadRootDir = new File(uploadRootPath);
        // Create directory if it not exists.
        if (!uploadRootDir.exists()) {
            uploadRootDir.mkdirs();
        }

        MultipartFile fileData = employee.getFileData();
        String name = fileData.getOriginalFilename();
        System.out.println("Client File Name = " + name);

        if (name != null && name.length() > 0) {
            try {
                // Create the file at server
                File serverFile = new File(uploadRootDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + employee.getiNumber()+".jpg");

                BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(serverFile));
                stream.write(fileData.getBytes());
                stream.close();
                //

                System.out.println("Write file: " + serverFile);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error Write file: " + name);

            }
        }


        if(employee.getiNumber()==null){
        empRepository.save(employee);
        }
        else{
          empRepository.save(employee);
        }
        return  employee;
    }
```

Here is the `Employee.java` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @NotBlank
    private String iNumber;

    @NotBlank
    private String fullName;

//    @NotBlank
    private String joinedDate;

    @NotBlank
    private String position;

    @NotBlank
    private String reportsTo;

    @NotBlank
    private String cubicleNo;

    @NotBlank
    private String jobType;

    // Upload files.
    @Transient
    private MultipartFile fileData;
//all getters setters constuctor
```

My image files are successfully loaded in `src\main\webapp\upload` directory,but I want images to be saved in `src\main\resources\images`.

Comment: This makes no sense. You have that directory on your machine, because the developer of this application. When it will be deployed on a server, this directory won't exist anywhere. All it will have is a file system (maybe), and a readonly war file containing the static code, resources and libraries of your application. Uploaded images are **data**. Treat them as such.

Comment: so what is the good solutiom?

Comment: To treat them as data. You store them somewhere (the file system, a database, an storage service), and to use a spring controller to get them out of that database and return them in the response.

Comment: But in my case i want to save images in resources folder and i want to retrieve image from there.Isnt it possible?

Comment: There is no resources folder in production, where your app will run. Only an executable jar or war file. The resources folder only exists on your developer machine, containing the **sources** of your application. Not in the compiled, runnable artifact. You can configure any folder on the production machine and store your images there. That will be your database. And you can serve the images by reading them from there, either from a controller you write, or by configuring spring boot to serve resources from this directory.

Comment: I understand what are you saying but isnt it possible what i asked in my question?

Comment: If you ask that question again, then you are not understanding. No, it's not possible. But it's possible to configure Spring boot to serve resources from a directory on the file system.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't really be uploading files there.

If you are using a war, redeploying will delete them. If they are intended to be temporary then use an os assigned temporary location.

If you intend to publish them afterwards then choose a location in which to store the files on your server, make this location known to the application and save and load files from the location.

If you are trying to replace resources dynamically such as an image which is referenced in the html or css templates, then consider publishing the external location separately, you can use mvc:resources for this e.g:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("file:/absolute/path/to/image/dir");
}
```

and you would save your files to that location. This will make it more permanent between deployments.

To save an image to that location using your code you will need to add this into your properties or YML file

```
imagesFolder:"/absolute/path/to/image/dir"
```

just add your logic to this.

```
@value("${imagesFolder}")
    private String imagesFolder;
    public void setImagesFolder(String imagesFolder) {
        this.imagesFolder = imagesFolder;
    }
    public String fileUpload(UploadedFile uploadedFile) {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        MultipartFile file = uploadedFile.getFile();
        String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
        File newFile = new File(imagesFolder + fileName);

        try {
            inputStream = file.getInputStream();

            if (!newFile.exists()) {
                newFile.createNewFile();
            }
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return newFile.getAbsolutePath();
    }
```

Please bear in mind that you need to change /absolute/path/to/image/dir to an actual path that exists, also I would recommend to look at the [Spring Resources documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#resources) for a better way to deal with files and resources.

Comment: I am using spring boot

Comment: Okay. So you creating JAR or what? SpringBoot also create WAR

Comment: I am creating war

Comment: I cant use xml in spring boot

Comment: Updated answer.